# get pid of specific application instance

Tags: bash, conky

Lets say I want to kill just the conky instance with the configuration file conkyrc_update and not the other one workload. Is there a way to get the pid of a specific application instance?

```
[sebastian@archlinux-work ~]$ ps aux | grep conky
sebasti+  4277  1.0  0.1 102724 11408 ?        S    15:02   0:02 conky -c /home/sebastian/scripts/conky_sysmon/conkyrc_update
sebasti+  4278  0.0  0.1 250136  9720 ?        Sl   15:02   0:00 conky -c /home/sebastian/scripts/conky_sysmon/conkyrc_workload
```

Comment: The second column in your `ps` output seems like your PID. :/

Comment: `ps aux | grep conkyrc_update | awk '{print $2}'`

Comment: "ps aux" is listed too. so I have two pids in two lines, but showing specific colums is a nice feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use pgrep with `--full` parameter (to match against the arguments too, and not only the process name):

```
pgrep --full conkyrc_update
```

and if you want to simply kill it, you can just:

```
pkill --full conkyrc_update
```